# The root user won't disable on my Mac, any ideas why or how to fix it?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, monterey, root

When I try disable my root user using Directory Utility/Terminal it doesn't disable. When I enter:

`dsenableroot -d`

it just returns "Failed to disable root user".

Not sure what on earth is going on, can't log into the user either.

Comment: How did you enable root. By default it is not enabled/

Comment: Are you sure it is actually enabled?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232491/how-to-test-if-root-user-is-enabled-in-mac

Comment: Yeah it’s enabled, when I run the command in terminal to enable it it fails also… so yeah

Comment: FWIW, my M1 returns "successfully disabled root user" when I run the command. Can you think of anything that you might have done to affect anything like this? E.g. Did you restore a cloned disk image of the disk? Have you tried running the command from Recovery?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo dsenableroot -d` worked for me, asking for the root password one last time after the sudo authentication.

> dsenableroot:: ***Successfully disabled root user.